# How to release these leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I am using `THCalendarInfo` class in my application. In this class i got memory leaks, but actually the leak shows at this line `CFCalendarCopyCurrent(),`. Actually in `dealloc` method it is released, but it shows the memory leaks. I send the sample code.

```
+ (int) currentDayOfWeek
{
    return CFCalendarGetOrdinalityOfUnit (
        CFCalendarCopyCurrent(),
        kCFCalendarUnitDay,
        kCFCalendarUnitWeek,
    [self currentAbsoluteTime]
    );
}

- (id) init
{
    [super init];
    _absoluteTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    _calendar     = CFCalendarCopyCurrent();
    _timeZone     = CFCalendarCopyTimeZone( _calendar );
    _dayNames     = nil;
    _monthNames   = nil;

    [self setupEnglishNames];
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    if ( _calendar ) CFRelease( _calendar );
    if ( _timeZone ) CFRelease( _timeZone );

    [_dayNames release];
    [_monthNames release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Which `CFCalendarCopyCurrent()`, you have two in there, the one in your class method is probably the candidate since that isn't released.

Comment: i follow this link Class http://pastebin.com/XiYkKfC2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your memory leak is in the `+ (int) currentDayOfWeek` method because you create an another copy of the logical calendar. Try to use existed calendar instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in all methods of this controller

Only need to release the current calendar before return the index.

```
+ (int) currentDayOfWeek
{
    CFCalendarRef currentCalendar = CFCalendarCopyCurrent ();

    CFIndex respuesta = CFCalendarGetOrdinalityOfUnit (
                                           currentCalendar,
                                           kCFCalendarUnitDay,
                                           kCFCalendarUnitWeek,
                                           [self currentAbsoluteTime]
                                           );
    CFRelease(currentCalendar);

    return respuesta;
}

+ (int) daysInCurrentMonth
{
    CFCalendarRef currentCalendar = CFCalendarCopyCurrent ();

    CFRange r = CFCalendarGetRangeOfUnit (
       currentCalendar,
       kCFCalendarUnitDay,
       kCFCalendarUnitMonth,
       [self currentAbsoluteTime]
    );


    CFRelease(currentCalendar);

    return r.length;
}
```